# Is re-ordering a resource considered PATCH

Tags: rest, sorting, patch, api-design

I am supposed to be designing a REST API where in the resources (say for example todo resources) are to be sent to the UI in an user created order. The resource has an `order` attribute which is an integer that represents the index in which the resource has to be displayed in the UI. There is also an operation from the UI where the user can re-order the resources - is it right to consider the re-order as a PATCH operation of type `MOVE` on the resource against the `order` attribute of the resource?

The re-order operation re-arranges or re-orders the list of resources modifying the `order` values of other resources too..

As per correct REST API design principles, what is the best way to design this?

Comment: How is order for the resource maintained/determined?  Is the ordering tied to the user or the resource (can different users have different orderings at the same time)?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, the default order is insertion order. An user can see or has access to only the resources that he/she has created. He/she can also reorder only those resources that has been created by him/her.

Comment: Cool, see my answer

Comment: @Ray thanks for the reply - I got your reply, just trying to be clear, so for my case `PATCH` replace is good enough- am I right?

Comment: Yes, if you're just partially updating a resource (in this case the order attribute of resources), patch is fine.  Just realize, PATCH is not guaranteed to be safe or idempotent.

Answer (score 0):

From your example `order` is a just an attribute, like `name` or `description` of a todo item.

Yes, PATCH is fine for partially updating resources.  Take note, in your case, You're not actually moving the resource, just modifying attributes that modifies it's ordering inside another resource (this list of todo items).

It sounds like we've 2 resources here:

- A todo item (with an `order` attribute)
- The list resources with several todo items.

A resource can be a list of sub-resources which may be ordered, but you're not changing the URL to the item or the list.

For example:

```
  /list/{list_id}/item/{item_id}  ---> specific todo item resource
  /list/{list_id}   -->  items in the todo list, ordered attribute
```

If the order attribute is tied to the item, then a patch replace is fine on the   `/list/{list_id}/item/{item_id}` or several item resources at a time at `/list/{list_id}`, but you're not changing any id's or URI's to either the list or item, just the order attibute of the item.